# bios.440.rom file for VMware Fusion 12

Tags: macos, bios, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

I am trying to change some system information (manufacterer and model), and I found many tutorials on YouTube to edit the bios.440.rom file on Windows. I'm looking for a similar solution for Mac. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but go to your `VMWare Fusion.app`, and then control-click (or right-click) on the file. You can click "Show package contents". Then you can navigate to `Contents/Library/roms/` and you should be able to find your `bios.440.rom` file.